# Truncate long text and change as links in the Pageblocktable - VF/jQuery

Tags: visualforce, jquery

In a table with six columns, I have truncated the DESCRIPTION field to 25 characters to avoid the row expansion. However, I wanted to make the truncated text as links, so that the user can click and view the complete description in a new window.

The code is as follows. When this code is saved there is only a partial output. Out of five long descriptions in the table, only the first one is truncated and underlined. Any description is not turned into a link. 
There are a few/many errors in the code. Great, if you could help me in fixing this.

**EDIT:**

Page:

```
...


< apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapclass}" var="wc>

...


<apex:column value="{!wc.types}" headerValue="Type" />


<apex:column headerValue="Description"><a href="#" title="{!wc.fullDescription}">{! wc.truncatedDescription}</a></apex:column>


< /apex:pageBlockTable>


...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're way over complicating this.  In your wrapper class, have a variable for both the full description and truncated description.  The truncated version can be generated in your controller. Then, in your page block and visualforce, generate a link to call a javascript method for displaying the tooltip / modal, passing in the full description as a parameter. Or, better yet, use the title attribute of an  tag to display the simple tooltip.

Here's an untested example using the title attribute mentioned:

```
< apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapclass}" var="wc>
    <apex:column value="{!wc.types}" headerValue="Type" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Description"><a href="#" title="{!wc.fullDescription}">{! wc.truncatedDescription}</a></apex:column>
< /apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Thank you @JamesLoghry. I was asked to truncate the text in jQuery, so I thought of completing truncating, display and popup in jQuery itself. But for now, I've modified the code as the solution provided and posted in the **EDIT** section. I think it will work, but I'm getting an error 'Attempt to de-reference a null object".  The variable **truncmsg** in the loop is causing this issue. Can you please have a look into it, please!

Comment: You're querying for ALL opportunities.  Adjust your query to look for only the record you're expecting. (Probably can just use the record from the standard controller, actually).  Additionally you'll want to check for a null description prior to calling the substring instance method.

Comment: No, not at all @JamesLoghry. I haven't asked for the condition yet. I'm developing a code for the initial requirement. Mostly, I think it would be based on the Stages. There is a same requirement for Cases (table with Case Comments and Emails). I'm working on that too. I'll check with the null description and get back. Otherwise the code is fine? and as you said, is it that complicated to perform this task in jQuery?